# Why does Hibernate insert my entity rather than updating it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So I'm trying to update the Board entity with its child entities (Lane's) as well. Before I update, I do a select first to put the entity in the Persistence Context but it still performs a bunch of inserts instead of updates.

Context: a Board can have multiple Lanes and a Lane can have multiple Tasks and in this case I'm moving a Task from one Lane to another and sending a PUT request to update the whole Board.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

**Board class**

```
@Entity(name = "Board")
@Table(name = "board")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Board extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "board", cascade =  CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Lane> lanes = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "board", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="board", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<BoardUser> users;
}
```

**Lane class**

```
@Entity(name = "Lane")
@Table(name = "lane")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Lane extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Board board;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "lane", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

**Task class**

```
@Entity(name = "Task")
@Table(name = "task")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Task extends BaseEntity {

    private String name, description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Lane lane;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="task_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="tag_id"))
    private List<Tag> tags;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "task", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<TaskUser> users;

}
```

**BoardController class**

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public BoardDto update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody BoardDto boardDto) throws BoardNotFoundException {
    var original = boardService.find(id).orElseThrow(() -> new BoardNotFoundException(id));
    var updated = boardMapper.toEntity(boardDto);

    var board = boardService.update(original, updated);
    log.info("Updating board with name {}", board.getName());
    return boardMapper.toDto(board);
}
```

**BoardMapper interface**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface BoardMapper {
    BoardDto toDto(Board board);
    Board toEntity(BoardDto boardDto);
}
```

**BoardService class**

```
public Optional<Board> find(Long id) {
    return boardRepository.findById(id);
}

@Transactional
public Board update(Board original, Board updated) {
    original.setName(updated.getName());
    original.setLanes(updated.getLanes());
    original.setUsers(updated.getUsers());
    original.setTags(updated.getTags());

    original.getLanes().forEach(lane -> {
        lane.setBoard(original);
        lane.getTasks().forEach(task -> task.setLane(lane));
    });

    original.getTags().forEach(tag -> tag.setBoard(original));

    return boardRepository.save(original);
}
```

**SQL log**

```
Hibernate: select board0_.id as id1_0_0_, board0_.created as created2_0_0_, board0_.last_modified as last_mod3_0_0_, board0_.version as version4_0_0_, board0_.name as name5_0_0_ from board board0_ where board0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into lane (created, last_modified, version, board_id, name) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into lane (created, last_modified, version, board_id, name) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into lane (created, last_modified, version, board_id, name) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into tag (created, last_modified, version, board_id, colour, name) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into tag (created, last_modified, version, board_id, colour, name) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into board_users (board_id, user_id, version) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update board set created=?, last_modified=?, version=?, name=? where id=? and version=?
```

Comment: I thought at first you're saving a different instance but you're correct. You're saving the original, modified.

Comment: Could it be that each time there is a new "name" to the board ?

Comment: I'm not changing the name and when I comment out original.setName(updated.getName()), the result stays the same.

Comment: I see something about the Id.   (Long id).  It is not copied in the update method.  It's probably in the Base and maybe even "AutoGenerated" ?   This is your PK so maybe it has a new value each time.

Comment: I would also check what happens to the Id in the toEntity() of the mapper.

Comment: Both the ids from the updated & original objects seem to match so I think the mapping goes fine as far as the ids go.

Comment: Is it defined as PK ?   (looks like it does because you're using it in findById).   strange!

Comment: It extends the BaseEntity class which has the @Id + @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) annotations on the id field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238152/discussion-between-pam-stums-and-mok-1).

Comment: Unless you have a method that does specific processing when updating an object, you don't need to rewrite the update logic by redoing the mappings, Jparepository can handle that like a pro. Make sure your interfaces extend JpaRepository and have a strategy for generating the id (```@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)```) defined at BaseEntity level.

Comment: No need to do the findById in the controller, just do :
```var board = boardService.save(boardDto);```

As said above the framework knows how to differentiate if it's a save or update depending on the presence or not of the id.

Then at the service level, the save method should contains:
```var board = boardMapper.toEntity(boardDto);```
```board = boardRepository.save(board);```
```return boardMapper.toDto(result);```